# Get webcam image?

Tags: c#, webcam, detect, image-capture

How do I verify if there is a webcam available and if so get a screenshot of what it can capture ?

I was initially looking for an easy to use library but I guess none exist and most of the information I found was like from 2006 and around.

For instance:

```
Webcam webcam = new Webcam();
webcam.GetDefaultDevice().SaveCapturedImageTo("path");
```

Ofc this is just me dreaming of a simple code but I wonder if there is a library simple like that or that you dont actually need to write pages of code to simple interact with a default installed webcam and get a screenshot out of it.

Comment: You should keep in mind that, there should be a client side "permission" for your request.

Comment: I believe Silverlight supports access to Web cams.

Comment: @Beytan Kurt the reason I want to do this is to capture periodically what can be seen once a device is stolen which should not ask for a permission otherwise the person who stole it would simple denied the request and the efforts would go to waste. I am currently creating an application like preyproject.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sites.google.com/site/webcamlibrarydotnet/winfrom-and-csharp-sample-code-and-download

Comment: seems to work nicely but I am stucked with how to change it to a different storage or save directly if you could here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596039/picturebox-to-bitmap-or-image thanks.