# PictureBox to Bitmap or Image?

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

I am trying to change the code http://sites.google.com/site/webcamlibrarydotnet/winfrom-and-csharp-sample-code-and-download from picture box to image or bitmap as I dont want to display any image or plan to display, all I want is that it will output the image to file.

I have tried changing the webcam.cs from `PictureBox _FrameImage` to `Bitmap _FrameImage` and `PictureBox ImageControl` to `Bitmap ImageControl` and casting (Bitmap) at `e.WebCamImage`

As well as changing it on the main form:

```
private void bWebcam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebCam webcam = new WebCam();
    Bitmap image = null;
    webcam.InitializeWebCam(ref image);

    webcam.Start();
    webcam.Stop();

    FileStream fstream = new FileStream("testWebcam.jpg", FileMode.Create);
    image.Save(fstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    fstream.Close();
}
```

- **Unhappyly it doesnt seem to work so
  how could I change it from picture
  box to Bitmap or Image or similar
  storage before saving it to a file or
  save it to file directly ?**

The source code I am using is:
http://sites.google.com/site/webcamlibrarydotnet/winfrom-and-csharp-sample-code-and-download

Comment: if you search SO, the Bitmap to Image question has been asked previously

Comment: Why you dont call just image.Save("testWebcam.jpg") ?

Comment: @Tony it is not Bitmap to Image it is PictureBox to either one of the 2.

Comment: @Anton problem is that image is always null, so the changes I have done to the source do not work which is why I am looking for help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the WebCam class, why not just use the `WebCamCapture` class directly (since you are not displaying this in a form) and handle the `ImageCapture` event directly. The event argument for the event contains the `Image`. You could, in the event handler save the image to disk. Alternately, if you want to use the sample and the `WebCam` class, and you have a form. Use a PictureBox but leave it hidden (set Visible to false) and then just copy the image from there and save to disk when you need to.

Here is some sample code of using the WebCamCapture class instead of the WebCam class. It should be noted that this code is based on the sample code from the link provided in the question. I have kept the style of the sample so that code lines up.

Edit: Adding example of using WebCamCapture instead of WebCam class. This code should be used to modify `Form1.cs` in the sample code.

```
// Instead of having WebCam as member variable, have WemCamCapture
WebCamCapture webCam;

// Change the mainWinForm_Load function
private void mainWinForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webCam = new WebCamCapture();
    webCam.FrameNumber = ((ulong)(0ul));
    webCam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = 30;
    webCam.ImageCaptured += webcam_ImageCaptured;
}

// Add the webcam Image Captured handler to the main form
private void webcam_ImageCaptured(object source, WebcamEventArgs e)
{
    Image imageCaptured = e.WebCamImage;
    // You can now stop the camera if you only want 1 image
    // webCam.Stop();
    // Add code here to save image to disk
}

// Adjust the code in bntStart_Click
// (yes I know there is a type there, but to make code lineup I am not fixing it)
private void bntStart_Click(object sender, Event Args e)
{
    webCam.Start(0);
}
```

Comment: perhaps you can show me an example ? I am changing the class because I don't know how to do the captures.

Comment: I have added a sample - another thing to note and has been pointed out in some other comments. Do not stop the camera until you have received the image captured event. You could make the capture event handler stop the camera after you copy the image from the camera. I will add an edit to show that.

Comment: thanks a lot for the time I appreciate it, it works wonderfully to what I needed, thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

Using reflector you can see that internally the WebCam class uses a timer to simulate a framerate. Therefore calling start and stop right after each other will never generate an image since the application doesnt handle application events (and therefore the timer tick event) in between starting and stopping. You should register on the ImageChanged event and call stop in there.

Good luck

** Edit: the start logic **

```
public void Start(ulong FrameNum)
{
    try
    {
        this.Stop();
        this.mCapHwnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA("WebCap", 0, 0, 0, this.m_Width, this.m_Height, base.Handle.ToInt32(), 0);
        Application.DoEvents();
        SendMessage(this.mCapHwnd, 0x40a, 0, 0);
        SendMessage(this.mCapHwnd, 0x432, 0, 0);
        this.m_FrameNumber = FrameNum;
        this.timer1.Interval = this.m_TimeToCapture_milliseconds;
        this.bStopped = false;
        this.timer1.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error ocurred while starting the video capture. Check that your webcamera is connected properly and turned on.\r\n\n" + exception.Message);
        this.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work even if i change the stop into the event or even if I dont stop, it jus runs into the save and throw a null exception.

Comment: How do you perform the cast? try using the as operator and do a check for null before saving (and stopping)
Bitmap bitmap = e.WebCamImage as Bitmap;
if (bitmap != null) { ... }

Comment: Not sure but its not guaranteed that the event will return a valid image each time, for example: the first event might come with a null value which is perfectly valid for a PictureBox

Comment: unhappyly i am not being able of solving this, no matter what i try it is always null.

Answer (score 0):

In WebCam.cs you have:

```
public void InitializeWebCam(ref System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox ImageControl)
{
    webcam = new WebCamCapture();
    webcam.FrameNumber = ((ulong)(0ul));
    webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
    webcam.ImageCaptured += new WebCamCapture.WebCamEventHandler(webcam_ImageCaptured);
    _FrameImage = ImageControl;
}
void webcam_ImageCaptured(object source, WebcamEventArgs e)
{
    _FrameImage.Image = e.WebCamImage;
}
```

If you modify the **ImageCaptured** code you can do what you want: **e.WebCamImage** is an Image.
for example you could change/add constructor to accept a file name and, in the ImageCaptured event, you could save image to file.

Comment: Like I said above in the question I did changed them but doesnt work ;(